# run loops successfully even when the conditions not met

Tags: python

I am new in python and I am working on code where the test shouldn't stop even when the conditions are not met. But if one statement fails then it should exit the `try` go to `except` and run the `finally` and continue the next loop.
Here is my code:

```
a = 2
x = input("Enter the value")
fail_list =[]
for i in range(0,10):
    try:
        if (a+i) == 4:
            fail_list.append("The sum is 4 at loop: %d"%i)
            raise Exception("Sum is 4")
        if (a*x) == 4:
            fail_list.append("The multiplication is 4 at loop:%d"%i)
            raise Exception("Multiplication is 4")
    except:
        print("Exception raised")
    finally:
        print("Loop %d passed"%i)
print(fail_list)
```

So, if the loop is failed at one if statement then it should not run the another if statement. 
the end result is to note the fail_list. and if the `try` is not completely ran then execute `except` and `finally` and continue next iteration

Comment: "it should exit the try". no. what do you think the `except` block does?

Comment: what result u are need

Comment: What do you mean by fail ( Raise error or doesn't match condition)?

Comment: use break to exit and stop your exceution

Comment: Hi @ravishankarchavare, I want that the test should run successfully for desired number of loops and at the end of the test, it should return the fail_list. It should not do double looping. So, if one if statement fails then it should exit that loop and run the another loop. This is just a dummy of what I want. The original code is really complex and large. The code goes in first if statements; it should append the fail _list and goes to except.

Comment: Add your Expected  output in output format not in text

Comment: and main thing you write finally block this will run for both condition means if raise error got or normal execution So you thinking that other condition is checking

Comment: @ravishankarchavare; i want is the script to run the _except. if the first if statement matches then the second one should not run and the it should go to _except

Comment: but your script is working as you excepted

Comment: @ravishankarchavare Is there another way, can i do it without adding `raise Exception("Sum is 4")`

Comment: If you use a `try except` statement, you need to raise an exception to interrupt the execution of the code inside the `try` block and go in the `except` block. Or by raising it yourself with `raise` as you are doing, or by execute some wrong code which results in an exception raised (e.g. you divide by 0). There is no other way. Unless you want to use another construct and drop the `try except`.

Comment: Hi @Valentino thanks! can you please give me an example for the 1st method.

Comment: Well, isn't the first method what you are already doing in your code? Raising the exception?

Comment: By the way, are you using python2 or python3? I ask because from the print function seems python3 (but adding round brackets is fine in python2 too in this case) but your `input()` makes me think that you are using python2.

Comment: I am using python3.Can I use `try` and `except` instead of `if`

Comment: First, `x = input("Enter the value")` in python3 should be  `x = int(input("Enter the value"))` if `x` is supposed to be an integer. Try to do this edit and see what happens. Maybe after this edit you will see what you were expecting.